# Is it possible to checkout Git Tag that was created in a previous stage in Azure Pipeline?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to checkout a specific tag in one of the deployment stages. The tag gets created in a previous stage like so.

```
  - stage: Create_Tag
    jobs:
    - template: create_tag
        parameters:
          version: '${{parameters.someName}}'
          tagPrefix: TEST-

  - stage: "deployToSomething"
    jobs:
      - template: deploy.yml
        parameters:
          deploymentTag: 'TEST-${{parameters.someName}}'
```

So adding a similar step in deploy template doesn't work. ADO is trying to validate it during execution and fails because the tag doesn't exist yet.

> ```
>     steps:
>     - checkout: git://repo/something@refs/tags/${{parameters.deploymentBranch}}
> ```

Are there any workarounds? Trying to avoid using multiple triggers.